# iPad AJAX Calls error out after 30 minutes

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, ipad

I'm in the process of building a webapp that is meant to be used on the iPad (saved bookmark, viewport tag, etc). The webapp makes an AJAX request (using jQuery) every 2 minutes to an unsecured server (eg. no session cookies that can timeout) that returns JSON.

However, after 30 minutes, the requests stop making it to the server, and I suppose stop being sent from the iPad. I've looked at the arguments to jQuery's error callback, which show `textStatus == "Error"` and `errorThrown == ""`. Yup, nothing for `errorThrown`, which is partly why I am mystified.

I've tried doing user-initiated AJAX calls after 30 minutes, which returned the same error. In case it wasn't clear, the javascript is still running: it's just the AJAX calls which fail. Also, this behavior doesn't happen anywhere but the iPad.

Any ideas why this is happening, or how to work around it?

Comment: Can you use Wireshark to examine the HTTP traffic to and from the server?

Comment: I wonder if there is some setting in the Ipad which prevents too many requests from happening over a certain period of time as sort of a security method preventing runaway requests on a wireless device.  I have no experience with Ipad devices at all though.

Comment: I think not: I changed the request rate to 5s and it still took 30 minutes. It might be a timeout somewhere in the settings, but I can't find it.

Comment: Okay, I somehow failed to note/notice this before, but the iPad only does this while on battery. This makes all sorts of sense, and points to some "network activity" timeout that isn't changeable by the user (At least, I couldn't find any such thing).

Comment: Add you own answer and accept it - it will help people searching in future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that the iPad 2 nerfs AJAX requests after 30 minutes of sitting on the same page (ex. a long-lived webapp) when using battery. There does not appear to be a user-configurable setting to change this timeout.

Comment: Random thought.  Does changing document.location.hash trick it into thinking a new page has loaded?  Would be hacky, but could provide a workaround.

Comment: I tried reloading the page every 27 minutes, which didn't work either, since it disconnected at the 30 minute mark, so I doubt hash manipulation will fool it.